# What is known about gradient descent on quadratic models (not loss functions!)

Tags: differential-equations, machine-learning

Let $\mathcal X$ be any set, and $f:\mathcal X\times\mathbb R^n\to\mathbb R$ be a differentiable model, meaning that for any fixed first argument, $f$ is differentiable in its second argument. Then we can perform (continuous time) gradient descent with $f$ using a mean-squared-error loss function, on some fixed training set of elements of $\mathcal X\times\mathbb R$, by which I mean we can solve the initial value problem

$$w'(t)=-\nabla_w \frac1n \sum_i (f(x_i, w(t)) - y_i)^2$$
$$w(0)=w_0$$

If $f$ is linear in its second argument, it is known that this is equivalent to [kernel least-squares regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kernel_method). For example, the training predictions $(f(x_i))_i$ follow a linear ODE with constant coefficients.

What if $f$ is quadratic? Is anything known about the dynamics?